# VPN Connected, How to browse files? Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, vpn, connection, network-shares

I am trying to establish a VPN connection to a server in my office from my laptop at home. 
I tried some of the steps as mentioned [here](http://theillustratednetwork.mvps.org/Vista/PPTP/PPTPVPN.html):

- Connect to a network
- Connect to a workplace
- Use my Internet Connection (VPN)
- Then type server IP address and then my username & password.

After creating a VPN connection, I can see I am connected to it. Now I want to browse files on the server. But I have no clue where I should look for them.

I was thinking more of a simple step, like, `Windows Run > Type ip address > \\124.345.678.900`, then a prompt asking username and password, and finally a window opens to view the files.

I tried to google it, but still unable to view files.

Please help.

**Update:**
I didn't mention that when I try to connect to server via `\\124.345.678.900` I get `0x80070043` error message.

Comment: Your conjured IP address is quite broken `:-)`

Comment: but it looks nice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. How have you confirmed connectivity to your office network?
   Can you ping to one of the internal IP addresses that you know?

   - Were you able to do a domain login into your office network?
     Typically a network-share is not allowed without domain-login.
   - Do you know that the server-of-interest is allowed access over VPN?
     Sometimes VPN access is differently access-controlled compared to the internal network.

---

Update after comments.

- Yes, the internal IP addresses are usually `192.168.x.y`
- Your comments suggest VPN connectivity is ok and you are allowed access too
- Since you can connect from another machine similarly,

  - What is the difference in this machine? (Is the other machine not Vista, for example?)

---

Update after new comments.
Google lookup on the error gives,

- [**Unable to connect to server...error code 0x80070043**](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vistanetworking/thread/82bedf39-a3ab-4ebb-8a1c-6c1c522e9a73)
- Microsoft [**KB932920**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/932920)

Comment: 1. -> Internal iP means 192....?? 
2. -> how do I do domain login?
3. -> yes, server allows access over VPN and I have tried it on another machine. and other people are using it.

It shows connected in my networks. Its just that I dont know how/where to view files.

Comment: regarding 1. -> Yes I can ping internal IP address. Just tried without connection, wasnt working. Tried Connecting and then ping to internal ip, and this time was working.

Comment: just checked ur update .. other machine is vista as well..  i guess is it something to do with my home network? router??

Comment: just added error message in ques.

Comment: +1 for effort & followup, regardless if this actually solves the problem at hand